# Ruby: Simple Creating & Writing a New File

Tags: ruby

I can create a Text File in Ruby, but my current code does not let me write to that new file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
newfilename = "16.Sample2.txt"
line1 = "BOOYAH"

out_file = File.new(newfilename, "w")
out_file.close
out_file = open(filename, 'w')
out_file.write(line1)
```

Comment: Aside from the error (`filename` is undefined, you probably meant `newfilename`), this works and prints to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real bug in your code is that you accidentally typed `filename` instead of `newfilename`. Make that simple change and this code will work perfectly:

```
newfilename = "16.Sample2.txt"
line1 = "BOOYAH"

out_file = File.new(newfilename, "w")
out_file.close
out_file = open(newfilename, "w")
out_file.write(line1)
```

That being said, you could make this code a lot better. `open()` is a generic method which lets you open any IO stream, including files and process pipes. `File.open()` is a much nicer method for handling files. It will automatically create a file if it doesn't exist, so you can simplify your code:

```
newfilename = "16.Sample2.txt"
line1 = "BOOYAH"

out_file = File.open(newfilename, "w")
out_file.write(line1)
out_file.close
```

But wait, it gets better! If you pass a block to `File.open()`, it will automatically close the file at the end of the block, so you don't have to remember to close it!

```
newfilename = "16.Sample2.txt"
line1 = "BOOYAH"

File.open(newfilename, "w") do |out_file|
  out_file.write(line1)
end
```

Using `File.open` with a block is what experienced rubyists generally prefer to do.

Comment: You found my error and helped improve my understanding too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- You closed `16.Sample2.txt` without writing in it (so it's created but left empty)
- `filename` is not
  defined

Let's try this one

```
newfilename = "16.Sample2.txt"
line1 = "BOOYAH"

out_file = File.new(newfilename, "w")
out_file.write(line1)
out_file.close
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir